# UFW Blocking Port 25 When set to Allow

Tags: email, ufw

I am trying to send test emails to my server and all I get in the logs is UFW blocking the IP where these test emails are coming from, UFW is set to allow all required email ports. I have not changed anything with UFW, everything was working a couple of days ago.

Why is this happening, what can I do to solve this problem?

UFW Setup:

```
To                         Action      From
--                         ------      ----
22                         LIMIT IN    Anywhere
80/tcp                     ALLOW IN    Anywhere
443                        ALLOW IN    Anywhere
6789                       DENY IN     Anywhere
3306                       DENY IN     Anywhere
993                        ALLOW IN    Anywhere
995                        ALLOW IN    Anywhere
587                        ALLOW IN    Anywhere
465                        ALLOW IN    Anywhere
25                         ALLOW IN    Anywhere
22                         LIMIT IN    Anywhere (v6)
80/tcp                     ALLOW IN    Anywhere (v6)
443                        ALLOW IN    Anywhere (v6)
6789                       DENY IN     Anywhere (v6)
3306                       DENY IN     Anywhere (v6)
993                        ALLOW IN    Anywhere (v6)
995                        ALLOW IN    Anywhere (v6)
587                        ALLOW IN    Anywhere (v6)
465                        ALLOW IN    Anywhere (v6)
25                         ALLOW IN    Anywhere (v6)
```

Also it does not seem to be just port 25, UFW seems to be doing a [UFW BLOCK] on a load of different IPs as well.

Output from iptables-save:

```
# Generated by iptables-save v1.4.21 on Mon Jun  5 20:44:01 2017
*mangle
:PREROUTING ACCEPT [65948:34120231]
:INPUT ACCEPT [65948:34120231]
:FORWARD ACCEPT [0:0]
:OUTPUT ACCEPT [62283:57804370]
:POSTROUTING ACCEPT [62283:57804370]
COMMIT
# Completed on Mon Jun  5 20:44:01 2017
# Generated by iptables-save v1.4.21 on Mon Jun  5 20:44:01 2017
*nat
:PREROUTING ACCEPT [4339:300646]
:INPUT ACCEPT [901:55631]
:OUTPUT ACCEPT [780:49032]
:POSTROUTING ACCEPT [780:49032]
COMMIT
# Completed on Mon Jun  5 20:44:01 2017
# Generated by iptables-save v1.4.21 on Mon Jun  5 20:44:01 2017
*filter
:INPUT DROP [315:21392]
:FORWARD DROP [0:0]
:OUTPUT ACCEPT [1:52]
:ufw-after-forward - [0:0]
:ufw-after-input - [0:0]
:ufw-after-logging-forward - [0:0]
:ufw-after-logging-input - [0:0]
:ufw-after-logging-output - [0:0]
:ufw-after-output - [0:0]
:ufw-before-forward - [0:0]
:ufw-before-input - [0:0]
:ufw-before-logging-forward - [0:0]
:ufw-before-logging-input - [0:0]
:ufw-before-logging-output - [0:0]
:ufw-before-output - [0:0]
:ufw-logging-allow - [0:0]
:ufw-logging-deny - [0:0]
:ufw-not-local - [0:0]
:ufw-reject-forward - [0:0]
:ufw-reject-input - [0:0]
:ufw-reject-output - [0:0]
:ufw-skip-to-policy-forward - [0:0]
:ufw-skip-to-policy-input - [0:0]
:ufw-skip-to-policy-output - [0:0]
:ufw-track-input - [0:0]
:ufw-track-output - [0:0]
:ufw-user-forward - [0:0]
:ufw-user-input - [0:0]
:ufw-user-limit - [0:0]
:ufw-user-limit-accept - [0:0]
:ufw-user-logging-forward - [0:0]
:ufw-user-logging-input - [0:0]
:ufw-user-logging-output - [0:0]
:ufw-user-output - [0:0]
-A INPUT -j ufw-before-logging-input
-A INPUT -j ufw-before-input
-A INPUT -j ufw-after-input
-A INPUT -j ufw-after-logging-input
-A INPUT -j ufw-reject-input
-A INPUT -j ufw-track-input
-A FORWARD -j ufw-before-logging-forward
-A FORWARD -j ufw-before-forward
-A FORWARD -j ufw-after-forward
-A FORWARD -j ufw-after-logging-forward
-A FORWARD -j ufw-reject-forward
-A OUTPUT -j ufw-before-logging-output
-A OUTPUT -j ufw-before-output
-A OUTPUT -j ufw-after-output
-A OUTPUT -j ufw-after-logging-output
-A OUTPUT -j ufw-reject-output
-A OUTPUT -j ufw-track-output
-A ufw-after-input -p udp -m udp --dport 137 -j ufw-skip-to-policy-input
-A ufw-after-input -p udp -m udp --dport 138 -j ufw-skip-to-policy-input
-A ufw-after-input -p tcp -m tcp --dport 139 -j ufw-skip-to-policy-input
-A ufw-after-input -p tcp -m tcp --dport 445 -j ufw-skip-to-policy-input
-A ufw-after-input -p udp -m udp --dport 67 -j ufw-skip-to-policy-input
-A ufw-after-input -p udp -m udp --dport 68 -j ufw-skip-to-policy-input
-A ufw-after-input -m addrtype --dst-type BROADCAST -j ufw-skip-to-policy-input
-A ufw-after-logging-forward -m limit --limit 3/min --limit-burst 10 -j LOG --log-prefix "[UFW BLOCK] "
-A ufw-after-logging-input -m limit --limit 3/min --limit-burst 10 -j LOG --log-prefix "[UFW BLOCK] "
-A ufw-before-forward -j ufw-user-forward
-A ufw-before-input -i lo -j ACCEPT
-A ufw-before-input -m state --state RELATED,ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT
-A ufw-before-input -m state --state INVALID -j ufw-logging-deny
-A ufw-before-input -m state --state INVALID -j DROP
-A ufw-before-input -p icmp -m icmp --icmp-type 3 -j ACCEPT
-A ufw-before-input -p icmp -m icmp --icmp-type 4 -j ACCEPT
-A ufw-before-input -p icmp -m icmp --icmp-type 11 -j ACCEPT
-A ufw-before-input -p icmp -m icmp --icmp-type 12 -j ACCEPT
-A ufw-before-input -p icmp -m icmp --icmp-type 8 -j ACCEPT
-A ufw-before-input -p udp -m udp --sport 67 --dport 68 -j ACCEPT
-A ufw-before-input -j ufw-not-local
-A ufw-before-input -d 224.0.0.251/32 -p udp -m udp --dport 5353 -j ACCEPT
-A ufw-before-input -d 239.255.255.250/32 -p udp -m udp --dport 1900 -j ACCEPT
-A ufw-before-input -j ufw-user-input
-A ufw-before-output -o lo -j ACCEPT
-A ufw-before-output -m state --state RELATED,ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT
-A ufw-before-output -j ufw-user-output
-A ufw-logging-allow -m limit --limit 3/min --limit-burst 10 -j LOG --log-prefix "[UFW ALLOW] "
-A ufw-logging-deny -m state --state INVALID -m limit --limit 3/min --limit-burst 10 -j RETURN
-A ufw-logging-deny -m limit --limit 3/min --limit-burst 10 -j LOG --log-prefix "[UFW BLOCK] "
-A ufw-not-local -m addrtype --dst-type LOCAL -j RETURN
-A ufw-not-local -m addrtype --dst-type MULTICAST -j RETURN
-A ufw-not-local -m addrtype --dst-type BROADCAST -j RETURN
-A ufw-not-local -m limit --limit 3/min --limit-burst 10 -j ufw-logging-deny
-A ufw-not-local -j DROP
-A ufw-skip-to-policy-forward -j DROP
-A ufw-skip-to-policy-input -j DROP
-A ufw-skip-to-policy-output -j ACCEPT
-A ufw-track-output -p tcp -m state --state NEW -j ACCEPT
-A ufw-track-output -p udp -m state --state NEW -j ACCEPT
-A ufw-user-input -p tcp -m tcp --dport 22 -m state --state NEW -m recent --set --name DEFAULT --mask 255.255.255.255 --rsource
-A ufw-user-input -p tcp -m tcp --dport 22 -m state --state NEW -m recent --update --seconds 30 --hitcount 6 --name DEFAULT --mask 255.255.255.255 --rsource -j ufw-user-limit
-A ufw-user-input -p tcp -m tcp --dport 22 -j ufw-user-limit-accept
-A ufw-user-input -p udp -m udp --dport 22 -m state --state NEW -m recent --set --name DEFAULT --mask 255.255.255.255 --rsource
-A ufw-user-input -p udp -m udp --dport 22 -m state --state NEW -m recent --update --seconds 30 --hitcount 6 --name DEFAULT --mask 255.255.255.255 --rsource -j ufw-user-limit
-A ufw-user-input -p udp -m udp --dport 22 -j ufw-user-limit-accept
-A ufw-user-input -p tcp -m tcp --dport 80 -j ACCEPT
-A ufw-user-input -p tcp -m tcp --dport 443 -j ACCEPT
-A ufw-user-input -p udp -m udp --dport 443 -j ACCEPT
-A ufw-user-input -p tcp -m tcp --dport 6789 -j DROP
-A ufw-user-input -p udp -m udp --dport 6789 -j DROP
-A ufw-user-limit -m limit --limit 3/min -j LOG --log-prefix "[UFW LIMIT BLOCK] "
-A ufw-user-limit -j REJECT --reject-with icmp-port-unreachable
-A ufw-user-limit-accept -j ACCEPT
COMMIT
# Completed on Mon Jun  5 20:44:01 2017
```

Comment: Provide the output of `sudo ufw status`.

Comment: Updated to show UFW status output.

Comment: How about the output of `iptables-save`?

Comment: Updated answer with output of `iptables-save`

Answer (score 1):

use the following command to check UFWs default rules

```
sudo ufw status verbose
```

You might find that traffic is set to: `Default: deny (outgoing)`

if this is the case, test sending an email after running the below command:

```
sudo ufw default allow outgoing
```

Comment: The output is Default: deny (incoming), allow (outgoing :/